# How does colonists morale work?

Tags: surviving-mars

How does colonists morale work? What affects it?

From the beginning of my game, it changed slightly, but nothing major. Even in a new well serviced dome, it seems it doesn't affect the moral.

Comment: I haven't quite figured it out yet, I do know that colonists who work outside the dome will take a -10 hit to their sanity every so often and this imbalance might be contributing to the issue. I'm testing that theory currently.

Answer (score 2):

According to: [https://www.yekbot.com/surviving-mars-guide-to-health-and-morale/#:~:text=A%20colonist%20at%20high%20health,seek%20the%20Medical%20Checks%20service](https://www.yekbot.com/surviving-mars-guide-to-health-and-morale/#:%7E:text=A%20colonist%20at%20high%20health,seek%20the%20Medical%20Checks%20service).

Morale is derived from how well you're managing colonists' needs.  The main effects are a performance modifier, and below 65 the formation of renegades (dramatically nonproductive colonists who will cause crime).

Answer (score 2):

Colonists are born / landed with a basic morale between 40 and 60 on a scale of 0 to 100.

- If the health is high, they receives +5 in morale
- If the sanity is high, they receive +5 morale.
- If the comfort is high, they receive +5 in morale.
- On the contrary, if the stats are low, they lose -10 morale per low stat.

If the colonist is religious and is domiciled in a dome that has been visited by a Saint, he receives +10 permanent morale (stacks with multiple Saints).

If the colonist is domiciled in a dome that has been visited by an Empath (breaktrough), he receives +5 permanent morale (stacks with multiple Empaths).

If the colonist is nerd, he receives +10 in morale during the 3 days following a research carried out (stacks).
If the colonist works in one of the 3 workshops, he receives +10 in morale.

There are also several researches / breaktrough that increase morale

Comment: For both Saints and Empaths, instead of _"is domiciled in a dome that has been visited by"_, a more accurate description is "has ever lived with in the same dome". A Saints'/Empath's "visit" (actually living for 1 Sol) only affects colonists that are _currently_ living in that dome. The bonus is attached to the colonists, not to the dome, which also means afterwards they can move elsewhere and still retain the bonus.